# Static Factory Method Return Type of Generic Class

Tags: typescript, oop, types

I'm trying to infer the correct typings for a Static Factory Method for a family of classes, where the parent class is generic. I want the return typing of the static factory method to be the parent class to abstract both children, but typescript infers an or type of both child classes.

```
abstract class Parent<T> {
  abstract readonly property: T
}

class ChildA implements Parent<string> {
  constructor(readonly property: string) {}
}

class ChildB implements Parent<number> {
  constructor(readonly property: number) {}
}

class Factory {
  public static create(guard: any) /** I want to the return type be only Parent without indicate in a explicit way the generic **/ {
    if (typeof guard === 'string') {
      return new ChildA(guard)
    }
    if (typeof guard === 'number') {
      return new ChildB(guard)
    }

    return new UnkwonClass()
  }
}
```

I don't know how to describe the factory signature to only return `Parent` to abstract both child classes, because both will have the same shape, and not have an or type `ChildA | ChildB`

I've tried to write the signature as Parent, then typescript tells me, that Parent is generic, then I change the signature of the create method to `public static create<T>(guard: any): Parent<T>` but I have to pass from the instance the type, and I want that ts infer the type that I passed to the children classes.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAfAgN4BQCCokM8CewAJgPb7ICeCADlA79cUCDwBcCEtQC%201aijQYAwgAsAlsjYBBBBoC2-ZLgMEIGbHkJEAytA34A5hRpIujAK7wOUABSsnNx8gsKi4lL2UI5OAJRU8vKKqOgI6lpsAEL6RiZmhJY45kQAcp4GIKKutLAe0N4QvgG47Fy8AkIiYpIIZRWi8ZSJCkqpAGJwjVB8bgKeIMgasAiQwBBLSKwQuH5OnjhsUsD4PPEA9ABUFwgA6mprCJwIAJIrahye2gB0c4hqorgEI0EG0%20HgIJ4oPgsEVCECeCJ6Pg2Ah8BxEL54YjKhAAO64AhITTaawIK5nKi0Oj6ABmCD84hEHDpewOCAAvJyEAByRgxbmDKnUli4CFQ1G4XFpYm6Xb7KBsWJChBJYUaOkMhG4ZkIVkKjlc7n4cqVKACynCujgyHQ-CS6UZTJyg5K4Wq6nW8V2qUAUSgQn83IAqvgANa4rhIFJgAVU4bUIA)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/wXRxVm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: You can just *annotate* the return type to be whatever you want, but I don't understand the example code enough to know what to suggest.  You almost certainly do not want to use `Number` or `String` types since those are seldom-used wrapper objects and not the `number` and `string` primitives that people use all the time.  What is `guard` supposed to be?  Where does it come from?  What is `ensureShouldBeA`? Where does it come from?  What type is `event`?  You wrote `any` but it certainly can't be *anything*, can it?  What kinds of things are you planning to pass in?

Comment: I just edit the post, I hope it is better explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* the issue you are running into is that the TypeScript compiler is currently unable to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow *generic type parameters* like `T` in the following code:

```
class Factory {
  public static create<T>(guard: T): Parent<T> {

    if (typeof guard === 'string') {
      return new ChildA(guard); // error!
      // Type 'ChildA' is not assignable to type 'Parent<T>'
    }

    if (typeof guard === 'number') {
      return new ChildB(guard); // error!
      // Type 'ChildB' is not assignable to type 'Parent<T>'
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown class')
  }
}
```

When you inspect `typeof guard === "string"` the compiler can narrow the apparent type of `guard` from `T` to `T & string`.  But this does *not* cause the compiler to say that `T` *itself* is now `string`.  Type guarding narrows the types of *values*, not *generic type parameters*.  And since `T` is not narrowed to `string`, the type `Parent<T>` is not narrowed to `Parent<string>`, and so `ChildA` is not seen as assignable to `Parent<string>`.

---

There are various open issues in GitHub asking for some improvement here.  A good one to start with is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), which requests that the compiler narrow type parameters via control flow analysis, at least to allow for certain property lookups.  Neither this nor related suggestions have been implemented yet, as of TypeScript 4.2... and it's not clear when or even if anything will change here.

---

Until and unless something changes, my suggestion is to do what you can always do when you know more about the type of some value than the compiler does: use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  *You* know that `ChildA` will be assignable to `Parent<T>` when `typeof guard === "string"`, so just *tell* the compiler that:

```
class Factory {
  public static create<T>(guard: T): Parent<T> {

    if (typeof guard === 'string') {
      return new ChildA(guard) as Parent<typeof guard>; // okay
    }

    if (typeof guard === 'number') {
      return new ChildB(guard) as Parent<typeof guard>; // okay
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown class')
  }
}
```

This resolves the error.  (Note that your actual code may still yield an error when you write `value as Type` if the compiler does not see `Type` as sufficiently related to `typeof value`.  If so, you can still do the assertion via `value as unknown as Type` or `value as any as Type`.)

Just be careful with type assertions, since it is now your responsibility to verify type safety in those lines.  The compiler can't do it, and if you are wrong about your assertion, the compiler isn't in a position to notice.  Accidentally lying to the compiler could lead to weird behavior at runtime.  So double check that `new ChildA(guard)` and `new ChildB(guard)` are really and truly of type `Parent<T>` before asserting.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.2.3#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAfAgN4BQCCokM8CewAJgPb7ICeCADlA79cUCDwBcCEtQC+1aijQYAwgAsAlsjYBBBBoC2-ZLgMEIGbHkJFGG-AHMKNOrC6MArvA5QAFK05uPkFhUXEpO0cASioEeXlFVHQEdS02ACF9IxMzQksccyJ8DwMQUWdaJHdoLwgff1x2Ll4BIRExSQRi0tEYyji5BSVkgDE4Oqg+FwEPEGQNWARIYAgFpFYIXFIyXwcPHDYpEiipK0LyKgU6Og0AMwRfcREOe72DhABeL4QAckiHH59SrXFi4CAeKD4Lq4ADuKU02h0u32UDYMTQWAKNieuBeCDeqLIAG4EAB6UkIDgAa2APGBA3pdweOLxBLYn2+P26ZSggMuILoeHBkOhcNS2nSyIO6Py1mILNeKLYxLJFOptPpCRBEDUQjh+FhCAAolAhH4fgBVfBU-AcGFQ4ZgQGVeIKIA)